# Why do the routes "/login" and "/register" not work?

Tags: flask, routes

My Flask application is not recognizing/using the two defined routes in `auth.py`, how come?

---

**File structure**

[image: file_structure]

**Error Msg:**
`Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.`

**Routes**

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/home (WORKS)
http://127.0.0.1:5000/profile (WORKS)
http://127.0.0.1:5000/login (DOES NOT WORK)
http://127.0.0.1:5000/register (DOES NOT WORK)
```

**app.py**

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/profile")
def profile():
    return render_template("profile.html")
```

**auth.py**

```py
from flask import current_app as app, render_template

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    return render_template("login.html")

@app.route("/register")
def register():
    return render_template("register.html")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't register routes to `current_app`, instead you have to use a class called `Blueprint` which is built exactly for this purpose (splitting application into multiple files).

`app.py`

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from auth import auth_bp

app = Flask(__name__)

# Register the blueprint
app.register_blueprint(auth_bp)

@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/profile")
def profile():
    return render_template("profile.html")
```

`auth.py`

```py
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

# Initialize the blueprint
auth_bp = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

@auth_bp.route("/login")
def login():
    return render_template("login.html")

@auth_bp.route("/register")
def register():
    return render_template("register.html")
```

See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/blueprints/ for more information.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I lost 4 days wondering, why my routes don't get registered. While the code is good. OMG! You deserve a beer or two. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have at least two files in which you have these routes. In your app.py file you have /home and /profile, they both work. They work because you initialised the Flask application over there.

Flask offers Blueprints to split up your application. You could create a blueprint called auth for example.

There is a specific [tutorial on this subject](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/views/#) as well.

I suggest moving the initialisation of the app variable to the `__init__.py` file and creating a create_app() method that returns app. In this method you can register your blueprints as well.

This method would look like:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    from . import app as application, auth
    app.register_blueprint(auth.bp)
    app.register_blueprint(application.bp)
    
    return app
```

Your `auth.py` file, for example, would look like:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

bp = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

@bp.route("/login")
def login():
    return render_template("login.html")

@bp.route("/register")
def register():
    return render_template("register.html")
```